# Three.js not rendering

Tags: html5-canvas, three.js, render

I am using the following code to render a Blender model (the default cube one just to start out) and nothing is showing up:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test page for the </title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script src="src/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="src/Stats.js"></script>
        <script>
        var camera, scene, renderer, loader;
            init();
            render();
            function init(){

                var container = document.getElementById('container');

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(10, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 500);
                camera.position.y = 100;
                camera.position.z = 100;

                controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
                loader.load('obj/one.js', function (geometry){
                    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({overdraw: true}));
                    scene.add(mesh);
                });

                renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                stats = new Stats();
                stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
                container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );


            }

            function render(){
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
                controls.update();
                stats.update();
            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Everything is placed in their paths correctly and all I get is a blank screen. Advice?

Answer (score 2):

Its because you aren't animating. The collada loader is a callback function so it finishes loading well after the initial page render and then adds the object to the scene. Since there is no animation loop, the page will never redraw once the model finishes loading.